# Initial values for oscillations about a point (normal modes problem)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators, normal-modes

I have the Lagrangian $L=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2) -7x^2+2xy-\frac{11}{2}y^2$. So the two equations of motion are $\ddot{x}+14x-2y=0$ and $\ddot{y}-2x+11y=0$. Hence the general solution (by using the normal modes method) is

$\vec{x}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
           -2 \\
           1 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$\big(\alpha_1\cos(\sqrt{15}t)+\beta_1\sin(\sqrt{15}t)\big) + \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           2 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$\big(\alpha_2\cos(\sqrt{10}t)+\beta_2\sin(\sqrt{10}t)\big)$.

But here I am asked to find the normal modes associated with oscillations about $x=y=0$. I suspect that this can be summaried by initial conditions for $\vec{x}(t)$ and $\vec{v}(t)$ but I don't know which ones.

Comment: I don't understand. The fact that these are oscillations around $x=y=0$ (or not) is determined by the Lagrangian itself. The free parameters you have (which would be determined by the initial conditions) would simply determine where do you start the oscillation and the value of the maximum speed, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you are asking is the modes that go through the points *x* =0 and *y* =0 *at the same time*. The most general solution you found does not automatically ensure that. I'd assume you are seeking solutions with $\vec{x}(t_0)=(0,0)^T$, the x-y-plane origin.

Now, typically, for just one oscillator, you may always hide the cosine mode into the starting phase of the sine mode,  shifting its argument into $t+t_0$. But this would not get rid of the cosine term of another mode. So take one step back and two forward, noting $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$ describes modes going through the origin at *t* =0, 
$$\vec{x}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
           -2 \\
           1 \\
         \end{bmatrix} 
  \beta_1\sin(\sqrt{15}t)  + \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           2 \\
         \end{bmatrix}  \beta_2\sin(\sqrt{10}t) .$$
But the action is indifferent to the origin of times, so we can shift by an arbitrary starting time, as mentioned,
$$\vec{x}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
           -2 \\
           1 \\
         \end{bmatrix} 
  \beta_1\sin(\sqrt{15}(t-t_0))  + \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           2 \\
         \end{bmatrix}  \beta_2\sin(\sqrt{10}(t-t_0)) .$$

Note the zero velocity (return) times will be now different for *x* and *y*, and you are invited to find them.